# map/unordered_map: Prefer find() and then at() or try at() catch out_of_range?

Tags: c++, exception, dictionary, unordered-map

When using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, what is the preferable way to access an element that might not be in the container? Should one ask permission or ask for forgiveness? Why?

That is,

```
if (mymap.find(key) != mymap.end()) {
    value = mymap.at(key);
    // do stuff
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

vs.

```
try {
    value = mymap.at(key);
    // do stuff
}
catch(const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suggest secret option C which avoids both non-exceptional exceptions AND doing the search twice:

```
MyMapType::const_iterator iter = mymap.find(key);

if(iter != mymap.end())
{
    // iter is item pair in the map. The value will be accessible as `iter->second`.
}
```

In C++ it is not idiomatic to use exception handling for flow control, which is what the second code example is doing. It will make it harder for maintainers to understand the code and, depending on the specific compiler, it may not perform as well.

Comment: The at after the find is indeed unnecessary, but what are the benefits to this over catching the exception?

Comment: I also like to use `insert` when I need either put something in the map or update an existing item, prevents us from performing the lookup (or hash) twice. `auto result = m.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));`

Comment: @Praxeolitic exceptions carry a runtime cost (actually the cost is paid whenever the scaffolding of `try`/`catch` are used).

Comment: @Praxeolitic Catches are expensive.  Exceptions should only be used to handle _exceptional_ circumstances.  If you would describe the container missing an element to be an error state then at() would be appropriate.

Comment: Does the answer change if we expect the key to be in the container? Using find always requires a conditional. The cost of a try/catch when no exception is thrown should be small.

Comment: `find()` is also the correct answer when building WebAssembly from C++ as Exception are not always supported, or if they are, then they may be done via JS (slower?). Lost a few hours to debugging this!